# how to preform subtraction on a string

Tags: jquery, string, subtraction

Aside from inserting illegal attributes into an  tag and invalidating my HTML, I've never done what I am trying to do before and will most likely benefit from this answer in other areas of my work.

I think the problem is I am trying to subtract "1" from a string "$(this).attr('num')"

This might work if I first convert "$(this).attr('num')" into an integer and then subtract "1" from it.

I am open to any other solutions. Thanks

```
//

$("#jumpPreviousButton").click(function(){
var imageNumber = $(this).attr('num'); 
  $("#bgImageBox").css({
    "background-image": "url(/galleryImages/worksImage"
    + imageNumber - 1

    +".jpg)"
  }).attr('num', imageNumber - 1);

  return false;}
);

//
```

Comment: If you dont want to convert too and from an int, have a look at my answer below which uses jquery's data method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### use parseInt but don't use parseInt without a [radix](http://books.google.nl/books?id=PXa2bby0oQ0C&pg=PA104&lpg=PA104&dq=crockford+radix&source=bl&ots=HHuno9s6eI&sig=xJafqBlVTBvweoD5R0x35MErsTo&hl=nl&ei=MENFTYHjOMKEOrjbxLgB&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

The parseInt() function parses a string and returns an integer.

The signature is `parseInt(string, radix)`

so the answer to your question is:

```
  var imageNumber = parseInt($(this).attr('num'), 10);
```

The second argument forces parseInt to use a base ten numbering system.

- The default input type for ParseInt() is decimal (base 10).
- If the number begins in "0", it is assumed to be octal (base 8).
- If it begins in "0x", it is assumed to be hexadecimal

why? *if $(this).attr('num') would be "08" parsInt without a radix would become 0*

Comment: wow. It seems strange that it would default to octal like that O_o but then again a lot of things about programming languages seem strange to me sometimes.

Comment: something with classc java and javascript and octal-systems-heritage... Trust me, I spent 4 days on this problem 10 years ago, when this was considered a bug, instead of a feature...

Answer (score 5):

As you say, converting it to integer first will help. Use the `parseInt()` function for that. :) (Or `parseFloat()` if it is a floating point number.)

Comment: thank you for your time Golez. I will remember parseFloat() as well for future reference

Answer (score 4):

Why dont you use jquery's [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function instead of `attr()` to add the num field to your tag.

1. Jquery's data will not invalidate your markup
2. You can add any data type in data, so there is no need to use `parseInt`

For example:
HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>hello</p>  
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$('p').data('foo',52);
var val = $('p').data('foo');
alert(val);
$('p').data('foo', val + 1);
alert($('p').data('foo'));
```

This will alert `52` and then `53`. You can see a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qk376/).

Comment: OK, that is really interesting. Using attr allows me to see the number in the HTML. Where does data() store information?

Comment: on the javascript object, therefore not invalidating your html

Answer (score 3):

```
(parseInt(imageNumber) - 1)
```

if the number is an integer.

Answer (score 3):

parseInt() function is your friend ;)

```
var imageNumber = parseInt($(this).attr('num'));
```

Comment: Thanks Marek. I was sure there was some function for this but just not sure what since I'm new to Javascript and Jquery